# The relation between these two kinds $\text{Mod}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

What's the relation between these two kinds $\text{Mod}$

$M$ is a subset of integer set $Z$, $M$ is a $\text{Mod}$ if $\forall x,y\in Z$, we have

$$\begin{align*}u,v\in M \Longrightarrow  x u+y v\in M\tag{1}\end{align*}$$

Can this kind Mod be extended? here, we are limited in $Z$,

[A module  over rings denoted A-mod here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module_%28mathematics%29)

$A$ is an ring with identity, $a,b,\text{...}$ is elements of $A$, $M$ is the set containing $\xi$, $\eta$, $\forall a,b,\xi ,\eta , \text{a$\xi $}\in M$,

$$\begin{align*}(a+b)\xi =\text{a$\xi $}+\text{b$\xi $},\\a(\xi +\eta )=\text{a$\xi $}+\text{a$\eta $},\\ a(\text{b$\xi $})=(\text{ab})\xi,\\1\xi =\xi .\tag{2}\end{align*}$$

(2)'s mod contains the (1)'s mod?

Comment: Where did you see the first definition? Also, your second definition is rather confusing to read.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Definition$1$ is the multiples of one integer, $Za$,$Z2=\{\cdots, -4,-2,0,2,4,\cdots\}$

Comment: Yes, I see what it is. I was asking where you had come across it.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Garding's encounter with mathematics, Chapter 2 and 3

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft - Hardy and Wright's "An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers" has a similar definition of a modulus of numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the wikipedia page you linked to:

> If R is any ring and I is any left ideal in R, then I is a left module over R.

The example you gave with $\mathbb{Z}$ is a special case of this, since your definition of $M$ is equivalent to $M$ being an ideal in $\mathbb{Z}$.